# Why meta-tag shorthand is only for meta sites?

Tags: support, tags, markdown, meta

While I was reading the [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), I found these lines:

> `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]` – link to the given tag's page.
>   Link text is the name of the tag. **meta-tag only works on meta sites**.

I know the scenario where someone wants to link to them is very small and probably it have never happened (and never will), but what made them take this drastic move?

My guess is that it was more like "not adding this feature" than "adding a feature to prevent the other feature from working", but maybe there are other hidden reasons invisible to the untrained eye.

Any one knows the story behind this?

Comment: If no-one ever needs it, why is not allowing it "drastic"?

Comment: Note on the bounty, since I cannot edit its description: The feature is available on MSE after all, even though it is something in-between a "main" and a "meta" site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because meta-talk should be limited to the meta site only; such subjects are off-topic on the main site.

The `[meta-tag:*]` syntax only exists because `[tag:*]` use on a Meta site links to the main site tags. That's because the normal use-case for `[tag:*]` is to be used in tag wikis (to link to other tags) and from Meta when discussing specific tags, making it impossible to do the same for tags on the Meta site itself.

---

Addressing Air's bounty separately: Nothing changed with MSE becoming a dedicated site; Meta.SO split off, this site was renamed.

On Community Building, the Meta site would *still be a per-site meta*. Linking to tags there is still out of scope for the main site.

Meta.SE is not more separate now as when it was called Meta.SO, and it being a separate site still doesn't make talking about tags here on-topic for any other site, and adding linking support for Meta.SE tags on per-child Meta tags would have to be carefully thought out as it would conflict with the current use for `[meta-tag:*]` on such sites. I don't really see a use-case here that is common enough to warrant separate link mark-up, however.

Comment: In general, yes. But I missed them when writing my nomination.

Comment: Just use a link to the tag page.

Comment: MSE is a special case; it has reputation like a main site, but you're correct that in this case, it acts like a meta site and allows the `meta-tag` syntax. My mistake for not thoroughly testing before offering the bounty.

Comment: The use case on Community Building is illustrated [in the revision history of this post](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/1062/revisions). I wanted to use the familiar tag Markdown to refer to the "featured" tag itself, in addressing the general practice of featuring things... yes, it's very meta. As the link demonstrates, there is an *acceptable* alternative, but linking to the tag is not in this case out of scope.

Comment: @Air: but there you were talking about a feature of a specific site. You were not talking about the tag, not really. In any case, if there turns out to be a real use-case and need on Community, I'm sure the feature could be made available just on that site. I am skeptical, however.

Comment: I think that's splitting hairs; the tag *is* the feature. But to be clear (publicly), I am not making a feature request—just looking to give this question some more visibility and prompt answers beyond "because it's off-topic."

Comment: A use case specific to a beta site with such low traffic would have to be *very* compelling indeed to warrant a new feature.